# Combine matrices with different arrays using loop FOR in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, combinations

I need to simulate data to get all possible combination of losses.
I need to combine a one matrix using several matrices with different dimensions. I have made these steps:

1. `g <- matrix(data=0, nrow=rows, ncol=columns)`

   I have made a matrix with all the dimension i need filled with zeros (in this case: rows=7, columns=3, but at the end I will use much more rows, about 1000)
2. Then i used a "for loop" to find all possible combination of losses:

> ```
> for (i in 1:length) {
>     g <- (combinations(length, i, data$loss_prncp, repeats.allowed = FALSE))
>     if(length<i) {
>       next
>     }
>     print(g)
>
>   }
> ```

in this case `length = 3, data$loss_prncp` is a data column with 3 amounts: 631.91; 16693.12;  8784.44.
And in the end i am getting three matrices:

```
     [,1]    [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 631.91 8784.44 16693.12
        [,1]     [,2]
[1,]  631.91  8784.44
[2,]  631.91 16693.12
[3,] 8784.44 16693.12
         [,1]
[1,]   631.91
[2,]  8784.44
[3,] 16693.12
```

But actually, the loop saves just the last value:

```
       [,1]
[1,]   631.91
[2,]  8784.44
[3,] 16693.12
```

How can i join those three matrices to one by inserting in missing columns zeros?

This is what i need to get at the end:

```
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,]   631.91    0        0
[2,]  8784.44    0        0
[3,] 16693.12    0        0
[4,]  631.91   8784.44    0
[5,]  631.91  16693.12    0
[6,] 8784.44  16693.12    0
[7,] 631.91   8784.44   16693.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
src <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
len <- length(src)
acc <- list()

for (i in 1:len) {
  c <- t(combn(src, i))
  zeros <- matrix(0, nrow = dim(c)[1], ncol = len - i)
  acc[[i]] <- cbind(c, zeros)
}

do.call(rbind, acc)
```

Output:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    2    0    0    0
 [3,]    3    0    0    0
 [4,]    4    0    0    0
 [5,]    1    2    0    0
 [6,]    1    3    0    0
 [7,]    1    4    0    0
 [8,]    2    3    0    0
 [9,]    2    4    0    0
[10,]    3    4    0    0
[11,]    1    2    3    0
[12,]    1    2    4    0
[13,]    1    3    4    0
[14,]    2    3    4    0
[15,]    1    2    3    4
```

Explanation:

1. `combn` produces a matrix of combinations (albeit sideways from what you want, so transpose with `t`)
2. make a matrix of zeros with number of rows = number of combinations and number of columns = total length - length of combination on this iteration
3. bind column-wise
4. outside the loop, bind all the accumulated matrices for each iteration row-wise.

BTW, I looked the the `combinations` function you were using and I'm not sure if you need that over the built-in `combn` function which is why I used it. `combn` just gives you all combinations of a certain length, which is what you want.